# How to compare two collections of ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 `ArrayList`s as mentioned below and I want to compare them: if any one of the elements is matched in arrays it should return true. I found the below solution, but looks like it's not suitable/working to compare the `Object` array with the `String` array.

```
array1 = ["accessory","device","pSim"];
array2 = [{"itemType":"device"},{"itemType":"pSim"},{"itemType":"NA"}]
```

```java
boolean anyMatch = array2.stream().anyMatch(array1::contains);
```

Comment: given that array2 is an array of objects, it seems like you are just missing `.map(/*a lambda to extract itemType*/)` before `.anyMatch(...)`

Comment: @ODDminus1, can you please help me with clear code?

Comment: You'll need to tell me what array2 consists of for me to help you. Is it an array of objects which has the field `itemType`? Do you have getters for the object or do you access the fields directly?

Comment: boolean anyMatch = array2.stream().map(skinyItems->skinyItems.getItemType()).anyMatch(array1::contains);

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean anyMatch = array2.stream()
                         .map(item -> item.get("itemType"))
                         .anyMatch(array1::contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data structures are not arrays I am renaming them to `arrayList1` and `arrayList2`.

You didn't really explain the types in `arrayList2` so I am assuming it is a map (it could have been a record or class with String fields).

**Given**

```
List<String> arrayList1 = List.of("accessory", "device", "pSim");
    
List<Map<String, String>> arrayList2 = List.of(
        Map.of("itemType", "device"), Map.of("itemType", "pSim"),
        Map.of("itemType", "NA"));
```

In the contains method you need to get the item from the streamed maps and see if `arrayList1` contains it.

```
boolean anyMatch = arrayList2.stream()
        .anyMatch(map->arrayList1.contains(map.get("itemType")));

System.out.println(anyMatch);
```

prints

```
true
```

**Note:**  It doesn't make sense unless it is a requirement to use `List<String>` for `arrayList1`. Duplicates would not make any difference so you could use a `Set<String>`.  Since sets are hashed, `Set.contains()` is more efficient.  This can make a huge different for very large lists.